# Read tables from MySQL databases into R

Tags: mysql, r, r-dbi

I'm trying to read tables from my database with `DBI` package in R :

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root', password='*******', dbname='powercurve', host='127.0.0.1')

dbReadTable(mydb,"3.4m140sco")
```

But apparently the tables name are not allowed in R because I'm getting the error :

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 

could not run statement: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3.4m140sco' at line 1
```

If in MySQL database I change the name of that table to something like `table1`, then I can read it in R easily.

Can somebody help me how could I read those tables in R, because obviously I can not change the names of all the tables.

Comment: Did you check `dbListTables(mydb)` to see if the table name is correct? What if you run `dbGetQuery(mydb, "SELECT * FROM yourtable")`

Comment: @docendodiscimus the names are correct  : db_list_tables(mydb)
[1] "3.4m140sco" "3.6m118sco" "3.7m144sco" "table1"     and the other command I have the same error !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can the backticks do the trick?

```
dbReadTable(mydb,"`3.4m140sco`")
```